# integrate search into header/masterpage of asp.net MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, razor

I want to add search for my website. Im thinking about using google custom search...
what I need is to have a search box in the header of the master page, and then a separate search results page when a user searches.

how can i implement this?, as the code snippet given by google seems to be for the results page I guess? also can i integrate this into a site that is still in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think choosing the iframe option when creating the Google custom search is the way to do it.
it separates ou the code into a searchbox, and a results page

Answer (score 2):

Implement the code on the results page as suggested by Google.  Then in your master page add the following

```
<form id="searchForm" method="get" action="/url-to-your-search-page/" >
  <input id="search" name="search" class="Search" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

The Google custom search code on the search page will take care of the rest.

**Update**

You can use the following JavaScript at the bottom of your search results page to extract the search query string and execute a Google search

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1');
    function OnLoad() {
        var s = window.location.search;
        if (s.indexOf('search=') >= 0) {
            s = s.substring(s.indexOf('search=') + 7);
            if (s.indexOf('&') >= 0) {
                s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('&'));
            }
            s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace('+', ' '));
        }
        else {
            s = "";
        }
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('your-custom-search-id');
        customSearchControl.draw('content');
        customSearchControl.execute(s);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

Don't forget to include your script reference in the header

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: this didnt work for me - any ideas? it redirects to my search page. nothing shows

Comment: What error did you see?  If you navigate directly to `/path-to-search-results?search=test` does you search results automatically populate with results for 'test'? If not then there is an error with you Google code on the search results page.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some JavaScript for the search results page